# Creating manual segue correctly through storyboard and xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm quite new to xcode, and I am trying to develop a sample app that is basically an embedded tableview which has many levels. I have a plist which stores the cells of each tableview. If the cells do not have children, then I want to be able to go to one detailed view once the cell is pressed. Eventually I want to be able to go to different detailed views depending on data type. To do this, I created a detailed view from storyboard, dragged my view controller to my detailed view to create a manual "Push" segue, and labeled the segue "segue1".

**Edit:** Source code [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/ufktZ6kq/DrillDown2.html?)

[image: Building Manual Segue]

Next I populate what I assumed to be the necessary functions for this to work, which is to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:myString];` where myString is the title of the cell I selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Check the dictionary to see what cell was clicked
    NSDictionary *dict = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *myString = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

    //If there is no children, go to the detailed view
    if([children count] == 0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:myString];

    }
    else{
        //Prepare to tableview.
        DrillDownViewController *rvController = [[DrillDownViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        //Increment the Current View
        rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

        //Set the title;
        rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

        //Push the new table view on the stack
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

        rvController.tableDataSource = children;

    }

}
```

Finally, I called prepare for segue which looks for the segue labeled segue1.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
    {
        DrillDownDetailController *dvController = [[segue destinationViewController] visibleViewController];
        //DrillDownDetailController *dvController = [[DrillDownDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [dvController setItemName:(NSString *)sender];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I thought this would work, but for some reason, whenever the code reaches `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:myString];`, it breaks with the error

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'segue1''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b4022 0xeb4cd6 0xdf61b 0x3590 0xa85c5 0xa87fa 0x93d85d 0x1488936 0x14883d7 0x13eb790 0x13ead84 0x13eac9b 0x139d7d8 0x139d88a 0x17626 0x23ed 0x2355 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)**

I can't figure out why it's telling me it can't find segue1 when it's already defined in storyboard and the code.

Comment: I may be COMPLETELY OFF here as I don't use segues much but try declaring `DrillDownDetailController *dvController` as an instance variable then in `prepareForSegue` set whatever properties you need to on the VC. Don't push the VC to naviation controller in prepare and then performsegue.

Comment: @mkral could you elaborate on "Don't push the VC to naviation controller in prepare and then performsegue"? So remove  the pushViewController line and put that line in a new performSegue function?

Comment: I'll add an answer that's formatted. If it doesn't work hopefully someone else can come along

Comment: I've updated my answer to address two key issues that I saw. 1. segue didn't have an identifier; 2. you're calling `initWithNibName` to create a view controller to push to, but with storyboards you should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A couple of problems, actually:

**First**, in that project you uploaded for us, the segue does *not* bear the "segue1" identifier:

[image: no identifier]

You should fill in that identifier if you haven't already.

**Second**, as you're pushing from table view to table view, you're calling `initWithNibName` to create a view controller. You really want to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Thus, the line that says:

```
DrillDownViewController *rvController = [[DrillDownViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

should say:

```
DrillDownViewController *rvController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableView"];
```

**Third**, your `prepareForSegue` was:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
    {
        dvController = [[segue destinationViewController] visibleViewController];
        [dvController setItemName:self->nameToSend];
    }
}
```

And it should be simplified to eliminate reference to `visibleViewController`, e.g.:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
    {
        dvController = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvController.itemName = nameToSend;
    }
}
```

**Fourth**, your `DrillDownDetailController.m` has this method:

```
-(void) setItemName:(NSString *)itemName
{
    if(!itemName)
    {
        itemName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:itemName];
    }
    label.text = itemName;
}
```

There are a bunch of problems here, but you simply should not be updating the `label.text` here (because it might not yet be created!). You should just eliminate this custom setter method completely (just let Xcode synthesize the standard setter for you) and just change your `viewDidLoad` to read as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    label.text = self.itemName;
}
```

Make sure you don't update UI objects until `viewDidLoad`!

I haven't gone through the whole program, but with those four corrections I can tap on "SubItem1", and then "Cars", and then "BMW" and I see a detail screen that says "BMW". I think there are some problems with your plist on other items (e.g. the shoes entries are strings, and not dictionary entries and you get an error ... I presume you just haven't filled in your plist completely), but the above fixes correct the more significant coding issues.

Answer (score 2):

THE MAIN ISSUE IS HERE, you were creating a blank DrillDownViewController, not reusing the one from storyboards, see comments in code below

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue1"])
        {
             [segue.destinationViewController setItemName:(NSString*)sender];
        }
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        //Check the dictionary to see what cell was clicked
       NSDictionary *dict = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *titleName = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

if([children count] == 0)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:titleName];

}
        else{
    //Prepare to tableview.

    //THE MAIN ISSUE IS HERE, you were creating a blank DrillDownViewController, not reusing the one from storyboards so it did not have a segue at all defined. instead do this:
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    DrillDownViewController *rvController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DDVC"];       
    //Increment the Current View
    rvController.CurrentLevel += 1;

    //Set the title;
    rvController.CurrentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

    rvController.tableDataSource = children;

}


    }
```

Comment: can you send NSString through the sender? Or is that frowned upon. most of the time i see sender:self but I didn't see any reference to the sender in the code so I assumed that I could send whatever I want as the sender

Comment: I'm actually not sure about that, but I don't think you should, instead you should send the cell that was clicked if anything then in prepareForSegue get the string.

Comment: because in this case the button/cell clicked IS the sender.

Comment: Looks like that didn't work, but I put my source code in the original post if anyone would like to take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Ill take a look at the source

Comment: Ok, I got it working but there were a ton of things I had to fix. It may be easier for you to just look at the source and ask questions if you have any.

Comment: Nvm, I corrected answer to reflex the MAIN issue. You weren't using the storyboard viewcontroller nib so it had NO SEGUE

Comment: Also notice that I set the VC's identifiers to DDVC and DDDC in your storyboard

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't know you have to manually link your storyboard in the code! A few things I'm confused about... In the storyboard xml.. I notice that you don't have the <classes> portion for the drilldownDetailController. How/Why did you remove that portion? And what is the difference between declaring a variable inside the interface vs. declaring it as a property? Did you redo the segue between the views as well? It seems like my segue was a little different from yours.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about the <classes> thing, anything I removed in there was unintentional I only used the storyboard editor, not the XML directly. Declaring it as a property will allow you to set that instance's variable without defining get and set methods. I may have added some unneeded one, the only important one is textName in the DDDC view controller. I deleted the segue, created a new one to check and also set its identifier (in your source you didn't as far as I could tell but your OP said you did).

Comment: Oh man... thanks so much! you've save me a lot of headache and taught me some things I didn't know about xcode. I really appreciate your help. It all works great now!

Comment: Awesome, go ahead and mark @Rob 's answer as the correct one. His clearly describes each problem which may be useful for the next guy/gal with this issue.