# How do I create a push segue with a button outside of navigation bar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create a button that can trigger a push segue in my navigation controller but I don't want a navigation bar, how could i do this?

Comment: this question might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518271/creating-manual-segue-correctly-through-storyboard-and-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these links might help

[Creating manual segue correctly through storyboard and xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518271/creating-manual-segue-correctly-through-storyboard-and-xcode)

[How to pragmatically segue from one view to another with button press from storyboard iOS](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/how-to-pragmatically-segue-from-one-view-to-another-with-button-press-from-storyboard-ios/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you know how to create the push navigation, and the question is on how you can remove the nav bar (if I'm wrong, let me know and I'll edit my answer).

In the second view controller add the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```